# VPN на localhost сервере

Tags: php, localhost

Вобщем у меня возможно необычная проблема. Тестирую авторизацию через Вконтакте на localhost. Все работает как нужно, но при отправке запроса на получение токена зависает и через 30 секунд выдает ошибку сервер не отвечает. 
Дело в том, что, там где я нахожусь Вконтакте можно открыть только через VPN. 
В браузере я VPN включаю, поэтому окно авторизации открывается, но curl запрос на сервер vk посылает localhost, который работает без vpn. Вопрос. Как можно сделать так, что бы localhost отправлял запросы тоже через vpn. 
Спасибо.
Использую XAMPP

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что вы используете браузерное расширение для для доступа через VPN? Если да, то только трафик браузера будет идти через VPN. Вы можете воспользоваться сервисом вроде TunnelBear, чтобы пропускать весь свой трафик (в т. ч. и веб-сервера) через него

Comment: используйте прокси CURLOPT_PROXY